# Разница в падеже при согласовании прилагательного со словами "стали", "были" и тд

Tags: склонение, прилагательные

Есть ли разница в том, в каком падеже согласовывать прилагательное?

Его глаза стали широкие, как блюдца

Его глаза стали широкими, как блюдца

Моё предположение, что именительный падеж делает акцент на определяемом слове, то есть "глаза - широкие", в то время как "стали широкими", оставляет фокус повествования на хозяине глаз.

Comment: Первый вариант разговорный, не академический.

Comment: @oleedd я слышал такую версию, что именительный падеж простонародный, но вопрос об акценте, есть ли акцент или мне кажется? Кроме того в первом случае глагол можно выкинуть из связки, а во втором глагол не заменишь на тире - значит разница не только в восприятии.

Comment: Нету. Обсуждали такое много раз. Есть такая (описана Розенталем): постоянный признак (1) и временный признак (2). Но здесь именительный плохо звучит, он больше для "быть".

Comment: @oleedd мне кажется, постоянный и временный признаки это широки(широк)-широкие.

Comment: Да, это тоже есть у Розенталя. Оно всё здесь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm

Comment: Больше материала: https://marjulia.livejournal.com/303704.html

Comment: @oleedd Он был старый - то есть рассказ про него, так как старый определяет "его". Конь был старый. Однако он был старым, когда я с ним познакомился - рассказ обо "мне", а не об определяемом предмете(человеке). Отсюда и временность восприятия. Он был молодой, когда я с ним познакомился - рассказ о нём, а не о моём восприятии. Тут дело не в академичности. Хотя последнее звучит кривовато, "когда я с ним познакомился - выглядит лишней конструкцией".

Comment: Оно даже на слух не академично. Это один пример с вариациями. По второй ссылке есть другие. А при "стать" именительный редко удачен. И именительный обычно используется, когда непосредственно человек характеризуется.

Comment: @oleedd Или вот, например, первый пункт из жж: "Глаза у неё были грустные" - про глаза, очевидно, потому что "у неё"; но "Её глаза были грустными" - потому что про неё, а не про глаза, глаза принадлежат ей.

Comment: @oleedd зато, "Он был молодой, когда я с ним познакомился" - звучит как прямая разговорная речь, рассказ о впечатлениях, в то время как "он был молодым" - звучит как мемуары, лишенные свежести переживаний, нет противопоставления переживаний и Я - все сведено к Я. В первом же варианте говорящий как бы отделяет Я от своих впечатлений о ком-то.

Comment: Тогда надо в первом варианте заменить "его" на "у него", тогда гораздо лучше звучит. Ну не лишённая свежести, а просто нейтрально.

Comment: Но всё равно "стать" тянет к творительному.

Comment: @oleedd возможно, потому что стать связано с изменением, а именительная форма согласования подразумевает постоянство. То есть "его глаза стали широкие" - как будто они и сейчас широкие, с тех пор)

Comment: Да, точно......

Answer (score 1):

Ср.: В некоторых провинциальных уездах Казанской губернии каждый четвёртый присяжный заседатель был мусульманином. [«Отечественные записки» (2003)]

Форма именительного падежа указывает на постоянный признак, творительный на временный. Так, в приведенном примере форма творительного падежа является двусмысленной: ее можно понять как постоянный признак, т.е. ‘каждый четвертый присяжный заседатель являлся мусульманином в течение всей своей жизни’ или как признак временный ‘каждому присяжному заседателю довелось хотя бы какое-то время быть мусульманином’. Хотя вторая трактовка маловероятна в силу внеязыковых причин, с грамматической точки зрения она вполне возможна. Употребление именительного падежа исключает эту двусмысленность.

Русская корпусная грамматика